# Too much whitespace at the top of the webpage

Tags: html, css, whitespace, padding

There is too much whitespace at the top of the page:
http://www.foundthenchosen.uk/

I've tried playing around with padding but I can't seem to make any difference.

CSS code:
http://pastebin.com/h2mGYXES

HTML code: 
http://pastebin.com/XAc7U3dM

Comment: Learn to use the browsers developer tools.

Comment: I've already tried all the suggestions, changing that value does nothing for me. I think this issue may stem from the fact that I have stopped the navbar from being a shrinking

Comment: It seemed like no matter what I did, I couldn't get the section to change. So I've removed the section tags, and making do adding some padding to the video. Thanks for all your help guys,

Answer (score 2):

Simple..

```
<section id="callToAction">
```

has padding of 100px so just remove that...

Comment: but there is no padding or white space in your site now? then where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

Change 100px for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you have that padding given to your **section id="callToAction"**
*freelancer.css line no: 166*

```
section {
padding:100px 0;
}
```

change that or write this in your css file at bottom :

```
#callToAction {
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS will fix your issue:

```
section#callToAction {
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```